# Help with Infimum and Supremum in inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have a problem let s2 = {x in R : x > 0}. Does s2 have lower bound, upper bound? Does inf(s2) and sup(s2) exist?

I understand the that the lower bound is 0 while there is no upper bound. I think I can prove that there is no upper bound since if I say let v be an upper bound so max(0, v+1) > v and max(5, v+1) is in S, which cannot happen. But I am stuck on proving that a) inf(s2) exists, and b) sup(s2) does not exists. I am not sure how to prove these two things.

Comment: Recall that the infimum is a lower bound $b$ such that for any other lower bound $b'$ of your set you have $b' \leq b$.  The supremum is defined analogously.  Does that help?

Comment: I got that part. But I'm trying to figure out how to prove this as in my notes my teacher talks about setting some epsilon > 0, which is where I get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch that maybe you can use in your proof:

We have $S_2 = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \; | \; x>0\}$.  What is a lower bound for $S_2$.  Is any negative number a lower bound? What about $0$?  Now let's consider what might be the greatest lower bound.  Can any positive number a lower bound?  Why can't $a>0$ be a lower bound for $S_2$?